# Convert date format "2018-09-27T00:00:00" to "/Date format (1468929882237+0530)/" in web api c# on postman

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a web api service in c# which returns date in "SaleDate": "2018-09-27T00:00:00" this format on postman but i want SaleDate in "/Date(1468929882237+0530)/" format.
Please suggest what needs to be done for that.

Comment: Looks like the date field has been already converted to string in c# before returning... If u just return the date as it is in the object, it should come in the expected format

Comment: Thanks Nitish.
I am not converting date to string.I have a property SaleDate of Datetime in my DTO.

Comment: Please add the web api code to 3xamine and any formatter setting in the api config if any

Comment: Do you want to amend your C# so that it returns the DateTime field in the expected format?  If so the issue is with the JSON serializer.  Take a look at this blog post, which mentions a solution by employing the NewtonSoft JSON.NET serlializer: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx